# Rails query on mutually connected models to hit a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Without breaking the data architecture that's in place I'm trying to query a list of on a connection between somewhat disassociated models.

The model structure is like this:

```
class Course
  has_many :course_groups
end
```

```
class CourseGroup
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :assignments
end
```

```
class Assignments
  belongs_to :course_group
  has_many :assignment_tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_assignments

  def completed_by?(user)
    UserAssignment.find_by(user: user, assignment: self)&.completed
  end
end
```

```
class AssignmentTask
  has_many :task_files
  belongs_to :assignment
  has_one :task_evaluation
end
```

```
class UserAssignments
  belongs_to :assignment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User
  has_many :user_assignments
end
```

**I'm trying to find out how many CourseGroups a User has**. Particularly those users that have completed all the CourseGroups that are connected to them. I'm not finding anything in particular that would allow for me to grab that information.

I was thinking I could some sort of multiple joins to get the connection like:

`User.joins(user_assignments: { assignment: :course_group })`

This gets me a list of users. In my CourseGroup model I have the following model:

```
def completed_by?(user)
  assigns = assignments.map(&:id)
  completed = true
  assigns.each do |assign|
    rec = UserAssignment.find_by(assignment_id: assign, user_id: user.id)
    completed = false if rec.nil? || rec.completed == false
  end
  completed
end
```

I can't quite figure out how to grab that method on the `User` model to query it or how to best rebuild it.

My first thought was maybe that I could build out my initial query as a scope and that I could grab the method that way but the scope fails, which is written:

`scope :course_user, -> { joins(user_assignments: { assignment: :course_group }) }`
I mean ideally I would be able to put in the scope the method.

Is there a way to grab the method in a scope or should I be just creating on the User model a method with the query and then recreate the method that I'll have to figure out.

**EDIT**: Added more classes and a method that's being used on Assignments. CourseGroup isn't traditionally being marked as completed. Assignments do not appear on a user's list until it's actually completed. They are instead assigned fully to the CourseGroup though. So a completed CourseGroup relies on all assignments to be marked completed.

So from the CourseGroup there is the completed_by? method that is then being referenced in a helper:

```
def groups_completed(user)
  CourseGroup.ordered.select { |group| group.completed_by?(user) }
end

def groups_incomplete(user)
  CourseGroup.ordered.select { |group| group.completed_by?(user) == false }
end
```

Not super easy to find out if a user has completed the CourseGroup until they have completed all the assignments and then those are added to their account.

**EDIT**: Updated the User model with some changes for perspective on where the code is at.

```
has_many :user_assignments
has_many :assignments, through: :user_assignments, source: :assignment
has_many :course_groups, through: :assignments, source: :course_group

def completed_ipp_courses
  completed = true
  all_users = User.joins(:course_groups)
  all_users.each do |group|
  completed = false unless group.course_completion?
  end
  return self if completed

  return nil
end

def course_completion?(user)
  collection = User.all.each do |top|
    top.course_groups.each do |list|
      list.assignments.map(&:id)
    end
  end

  completed = true
  collection.each do |assign|
    rec = UserAssignment.find_by(assignment_id: assign, user_id: user.id)
    completed = false if rec.nil? || rec.completed == false
  end
end
```

The idea being that the completed method does the join and checks for completed within the completion? method. The completion? method is running all the users through and doing the check on the UserAssignments for complete. No errors until...rec line. It now returns undefined local variable or method on user

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
class User
  has_many :user_assignments
  has_many :assignments, through: :user_assignments, source: :assignment
  has_many :course_groups, through: :assignments, source: :course_group
end

user = User.last
user.course_groups
```

Coming to the second part where you want to `Particularly those users that have completed all the CourseGroups that are connected to them.` I would say need more details about what are the conditions for `completing a CourseGroup`.

**EDIT**

Variable names are quite misleading e.g.

```
def completed_ipp_courses
  completed = true
  all_users = User.joins(:course_groups)
  all_users.each do |group|
  completed = false unless group.course_completion?
  end
  return self if completed

  return nil
end


def course_completion?(user)
  collection = User.all.each do |top|
    top.course_groups.each do |list|
      list.assignments.map(&:id)
    end
  end

  completed = true
  collection.each do |assign|
    rec = UserAssignment.find_by(assignment_id: assign, user_id: user.id)
    completed = false if rec.nil? || rec.completed == false
  end
end
```

1. You get users from  -> `all_users = User.joins(:course_groups)`
2. The you loop over `all_users` which is called a `group`.
3. Now `group.course_completion?` is calling a method in `User` model but if I go by `variable name` it should go to `Group model`.
4. Since `group` in loop is a user instance it will try to call `course_completion?` in `User` model.
5. Again, you are calling  `course_completion?` on `user` instance which accepts a parameter `user`, but not being passed from where you are calling the method.

Suggestion : A better naming can already avoid a lot of problems like :

```
def completed_ipp_courses
  completed = true
  users = User.joins(:course_groups)
  users.each do |user|
    break unless completed
    completed = false unless user.course_completion?
  end
  completed ? self : nil
end
```

Comment: Tried the through with source options but I end up with undefined method 'course_groups'

Comment: can you update your question and show the final class structure

Comment: I updated your question does your classes look similar to what I updated ?

Comment: It does. I'm going to an update as it's probably close.

Comment: updated answer for you Jake. Needs some more clarity.

Comment: That looks a lot cleaner. I think my idea was to create a method to handle the connection to course_groups and then handle the completion in a different method. The completion is looking at UserAssignments where either a nil or set to false.